# Cannot dereference generic iterator type

Tags: c++11, iterator

I was just trying to build something that involved a generic iterator type, specifically something that chains iterators, but I cannot dereference the iterator. MVE:

```
#include <iterator>

#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1};
    std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int> my_iterator = a.begin();
    int my_int = *my_iterator;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
iterator.cxx:6:57: error: no viable conversion from 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::iterator'
      (aka '__wrap_iter<int *>') to 'std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int>'
    std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int> my_iterator = a.begin();
                                                        ^             ~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:531:29: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter<int *>') to 'const
      std::__1::iterator<std::__1::random_access_iterator_tag, int, long, int *, int &> &' for 1st argument
struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS iterator
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:531:29: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter<int *>') to
      'std::__1::iterator<std::__1::random_access_iterator_tag, int, long, int *, int &> &&' for 1st argument
1 error generated.
```

Is there some other generic iterator class I'm unaware of that has this functionality?

Comment: The problem begins not with the dereference, but with the initialization of `my_iterator`. `std::vector::iterator` (as returned by `a.begin()`) is not compatible with `std::iterator`.

Comment: What if I want to use `std::map::iterator` and `std::vector::iterator` together? Shouldn't there be a base class?

Comment: No there isn't. All standard iterator types are specifically tied to their container, there's no common base.

Comment: If you make a comment explaining that I can turn it into an answer.

Comment: And if you want generic in C++, you have to use templates. Note how all standard library functions handling ranges all use templates for iterators. See for example [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). That function can be used with any kind of container with [input iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator), like vectors, maps, sets or deques.

Comment: Would a template automatically bind to `std::map::iterator` or `std::vector::iterator` though? I understand I'd have to change `int` to `std::pair<int, int>` in my example, but the general principle holds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197148/discussion-between-hameer-abbasi-and-some-programmer-dude).

Answer (score 1):

`std::iterator` isn't an Iterator, it exists to abbreviate defining one. It's implementation defined if the standard container's iterators derive from it, which is why the assignment works on your compiler.

> Is there some other generic iterator class I'm unaware of that has this functionality?

No. The C++ way is to write a template, e.g.

```
template <typename Iterator>
int dereference(Iterator it) { return *it; }
```